# Logistic regression accounting for temporal correlation (year)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, autocorrelation

I have as simple logistic model looking at predation of bird nest (predated vs not predated) as a function of the age of the nest. However, the data are collected over several years and there might be dependency between successive years. Is there a way to control for temporal autocorrelation in R: glm()? when running logistic regression?

Simple model without controlling for 'Year'

```
fit1 = glm(Predation ~ Nest_age, data = Bird, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```